# Converting Java Retrofit callback to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have this Java code:

```
Services.nfGetIncreasedRiskZones(new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
  }
});
```

The service it is calling:

```
public static void nfGetIncreasedRiskZones(Callback callback) {
  NfGetIncreasedRiskZones service = App.getRetrofitWithHeaders(App.getBaseUrl()).create(NfGetIncreasedRiskZones.class);
  Call call = service.getRiskZones();
  call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

And the NfGetIncreasedRiskZones interface:

```
interface NfGetIncreasedRiskZones {
  @GET(Constants.NfGetIncreasedRiskZones)
  Call getRiskZones();
}
```

The retrofit Callback interface look like this:

```
public interface Callback<T> {
  void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response);

  void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t);
}
```

How can I convert the first part, the "Services.nfGetIncreasedRiskZones", to Kotlin

Thank you

Comment: What the meaning of 'convert to Kotlin'? Only convert to kotlin codes? Or convert to sync function in kotlin?

Comment: @leimenghao I am converting the class containing the call to Services.nfGetIncreasedRiskZones to Kotlin, so I mean convertring that whole lumb of code. My attempt to convert the Java callback imlementation to a Kotlin lambda has failed so far, maybe because it does not specify a type?

Comment: 1. You can use `object: Callback {}` to create an anonymous class;  2. You can create an inner class like `inner class MyCallback: Callback {}` and passing to function `Services.nfGetIncreasedRiskZones(MyCallback())`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is, that you are interested in how to instantiate anonymous interfaces in Kotlin and this is probably how you'd do it. Here is a quick example I hacked together on my Kotlin REPL. It's probably not the same interface you are using but it should work the same way.

```
import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.Callback
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException

val callback = object: Callback {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, t: Response?){
        println("onResponse")
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call?, t: IOException?){
        println("onFailure")
    }
}

callback.onFailure(null, null) //prints "onFailure"
callback.onResponse(null, null) //prints "onSuccess"
```

So basically you need the `object:` in front of your interface and you don't need the `()` after the interface. The rest is more or less the same except for the slightly different syntax.

BTW: If you are sure that the parameters of the methods are never null, you don't need the `?` after the parameter type.

Here I implemented a sample `Service` and set the anonymous callback, then run it:

```
class Service {
    companion object {
        var cb: Callback? = null
        fun set(callback: Callback){
            cb = callback
        }

        fun run() {
            cb?.onResponse(null, null)
        }
    }
}

Service.set(object: Callback{
    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, t: Response?){
        println("onResponse")
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call?, t: IOException?){
        println("onFailure")
    }
})

Service.run() //prints "onResponse"
```

Comment: Yes instantiatint a anonymous interfaces is what I am looking for, but my Callback wants me to specify a type I think, I get this error: Type mismatch. Required:
(Callback<Any!>..Callback<*>?)

Comment: I have added the Callback interface to the question